# How to work on different gcloud (google cloud) projects easily

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud

At the moment when I change projects I set the following in the terminal:

```sh
gcloud config set account <name>@gmail.com
gcloud config set project <project-id>
export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS="<path-to-key>.json"
```

while this works, it seems a little clunky.

I could create something such as:

```sh
function project_1() {
    gcloud config set account <name-1>@gmail.com
    gcloud config set project <project-id-1>
    export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS="<path-to-key-1>.json"
}

function project_2() {
    gcloud config set account <name-2>@gmail.com
    gcloud config set project <project-id-2>
    export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS="<path-to-key-2>.json"
}
```

And call those methods, but it feels as though it's a common enough task that there would be something simpler.

So my question is - how should I go about changing projects, or is the above approach typical?

Comment: That's pretty much what I use as well.  I preface my functions with `gcp` and I don't export the credentials (I use HashiCorp Vault to provision dynamic creds when I need them).  But yeah, that's pretty much how I do it too. :)

Comment: Your method is fine. Also, consider using **configurations** which support what you need plus a lot more CLI options. I wrote an article on this topic: https://www.jhanley.com/google-cloud-understanding-gcloud-configurations/

Answer (score 3):

One important consideration with using `gcloud config` is that the state (and the current configuration) is shared by all the user's `gcloud` processes on the machine.

The config is also implicit using this approach. From which project (production|dev?) is `gcloud compute instances delete my-instance` applied?

I prefer to **not** use `gcloud config` for anything other than the current account (but you can also be explicit about this value too) and always use e.g. `--project`, `--region` etc flags on the command-line, i.e. `gcloud compute instances delete my-instance --project=dev`

I think this is particularly relevant in shell scripts where the additional typing of the config flags is worthwhile for the extra clarity that it provides.

Comment: This is a good answer. However, the CLI is per user, not per machine unless configured that way.

Comment: Thanks. That's correct but if you open multiple terminal sessions, `gcloud config set` in one, applies to the `gcloud config` in all the user's other sessions too.

Comment: Added the "per user" clarity to my answer, thanks @john-hanley

Comment: Thanks for the context around gcloud - i wasn't aware of that. Do you have any comment on the approach that I've outlined in the question though?

Comment: I tried to respond specifically to your approach in my answer. I would discourage your approach of using `gcloud config` to share state particularly in scripts. If another of your sessions, changes the shared state while your script is running, you will experience non-deterministic behavior. Ironically, since you're including `account` and `project` in your functions anyway, I would `gcloud some-command --account=${ACCOUNT} --project=${PROJECT}` and be explicit about the use.

Comment: @DazWilkin thank you for the follow up, re "_ Ironically, since..._",  makes sense to be explicit :) Are you suggesting that i have env variables `ACCOUNT` and `PROJECT`, or is that just a shorthand for commenting here? Eg - I could use these explicitly, and instead of having functions like `project_1` I could set env variables, but that would still have the issue you've outlined I think.

Comment: You can do whatever you wish. Using constants is inflexible and, since you're developing functions, it would be prudent for these to take arguments. I use `ACCOUNT` and `PROJECT` as variables. It's important to understand this is *still* better than relying on global state. Using global state, you don't know whether another process has changed the global state. With variables, only your current process could have made the change.

Answer (score 0):

I am using the exact same approach - i have 5-6 projects. I am not sure if there is a better approach, but at least this one works. :)